# My Blueprint CSS doesn't work with an uneven number of columns

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, blueprint-css, css-multicolumn-layout

I am using Blueprint CSS on a Rails app. I am making this a 4-column layout with a box around each item. If I have 4 items or 8 items, then everything is fine and I have 2 rows of products. If I have a 9th product or anything not divisible by 4, then the rows and items become disjointed and spills over to the next column. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```css
div.four-column {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-width: 10em;
    -webkit-column-width: 10em;
    column-width: 10em;
    width: 910px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <li class="box">
      <%= link_to product.name, product_path(:id) %></br>
      <%= product.price %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

mmm a quick fix might be do just do something like so

```
<% @count_diff = @products.divmod(4) >
<ul>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <li class="box">
      <%= link_to product.name, product_path(:id) %></br>
      <%= product.price %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
  <% if @count_diff[1] > 0 %>
    <% @count_diff[1].each do |empties| %>
      <li class="box">&nbsp;</li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

At least i think that's the right code :-) i'm still learning myself. but basically the hack i've provided will just fill in "empty" li tags to balance it all out. So if you have 9 productions it'll make 3 extra empty li's.

There's probably a more "ruby way" of doing it.

Comment: thanks for the code.  Unfortunately, this didn't work as it didn't recognize divmod. I got the undefined method error because (I think) divmod can only be used with integers.  A workaround it would be to do `@products.count.divmod(4)`.  I am still working on the rest of your hack.  Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Currently, the next error is `undefined method 'each' for 1:Fixnum` for the `@count_diff[1].each do |empties|`

Comment: what about doing @products.length.divmod(4) instead of count?